# Remove shadow from UIContextMenu so it doesn‘t shows in the dismiss animation Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicontextmenuconfiguration

In my app I have a UITableView with text messages in it. I already implemented context menus for it so it shows quick actions for a message when you press on it. My only problem is that when the context menu preview dismisses a small shadow is shown under the message like in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lp9j2.jpg).
This probably happens because the context menu has a basic shadow behind it, while it is shown and when it dismisses, the shadow just shows then.
Does anybody know how to remove shadows in general from UIContextMenus?

Comment: You shouldn't need to disable a user interface feature of a system provided component.  If there is a drawing artifact, then you should report it as a bug.  Perhaps if you showed a bit more code about how your table view cells are created and how the context menu is presented?

Comment: TBH I dont think the shadow you showed in picture has anything to do with context menu, instead looks like cell's selected state, may be when user taps on a message underlying tableview cell gets selected, try setting `cell.selectionStyle = .none` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`